# Ignore JSON parsing error if a field returns TypeError

Tags: javascript, json, api, error-handling

This feels like a totally straightforward try/catch issue, but as a total javascript noob I am clearly missing something.

I am trying to parse data from the Cleveland Museum of Art open collections API.  Everything works fine, except that some works do not name the artists involved.

When there is an artist included in the metadata (for example [here](https://openaccess-api.clevelandart.org/api/artworks/?limit=10&indent=1&cc0=1&has_image=1&skip=14660)) this snippet effectively pulls it:

jsonObj['data'][0]['creators'][0]['description']

When there is not an artist in the metadata (for example [here](https://openaccess-api.clevelandart.org/api/artworks/?limit=10&indent=1&cc0=1&has_image=1&skip=19673)), I get a

> TypeError: jsonObj.data[0].creators[0] is undefined

error.

The internet suggests that this is a perfect time to use a try/catch statement:

```
var data_author = tryCatch(jsonObj['data'][0]['creators'][0]['description'])

var function_image_data = [data_author]

function tryCatch(json_address) {
    try {
         output_json_data = json_address
     }
     catch (e) {
         output_json_data = ''

     }

      return output_json_data
  }
```

While that works when there is an entry for the author, it appears to have no impact when there is an error. What incredibly obvious thing am I missing from this statement?

Thank you!

EDIT: Based on tex's suggestions below, I moved the attempt to get data out of the function and directly into the code. I'm not entirely sure why it works, but it does avoid the possibility that things are being evaluated before they hit the function.  The section that searches for all of the elements of a work now looks like:

```
    var data_tombstone = tryCatch(jsonObj['data'][0]['tombstone'])
    console.log(data_tombstone)
    var data_title = tryCatch(jsonObj['data'][0]['title'])
    try {
         data_author = jsonObj['data'][0]['creators'][0]['description']
     }
     catch (e) {
         data_author = ''

     }
    var data_creation_date = tryCatch(jsonObj['data'][0]['creation_date'])
```

Comment: Can  you post sample json as well as you section of your code where you are parsing? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry! The links didn't make it to posting. I just updated the question with links to an entry with creators and one without.  Thanks!

Comment: This looks like pseudocode to me. I think you'll have better luck if you post some actual code you're trying to get working.

Comment: That's a snippet of the actual code I'm using. I just edited the question to include the call of the function and the array I add the result to. If you need anything else I'm happy to add it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jsonObj['data'][0]['creators'][0]['description']` is being evaluated before your `tryCatch` function is ever called, which means the error won't be caught.

If you're open to using a library, I suggest [Ramda](https://ramdajs.com/). Here's a solution using Ramda (that doesn't involve `try..catch`:

```js
const works = { data: [{ creators: [{ description: 'an author'}] }] }
const doesntWork = { data: [{ creators: [] }] }

const getAuthor = R.pathOr('', ['data', 0, 'creators', 0, 'description'])

const data_author_works = getAuthor(works)

const data_author_doesnt_work = getAuthor(doesntWork)

console.log('works: ', data_author_works)
console.log('doesn\'t work: ', data_author_doesnt_work)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

If you don't want to use a library, and do want to use `try...catch`, you'll need to do something like this, but I wouldn't recommend this approach:

```js
const works = { data: [{ creators: [{ description: 'an author'}] }] }
const doesntWork = { data: [{ creators: [] }] }

const getAuthor = jsonData => {
  try {
    return jsonData.data[0].creators[0].description
  }
  catch (e) {
    return ''
  }
}

const data_author_works = getAuthor(works)
const data_author_doesnt_work = getAuthor(doesntWork)

console.log('works: ', data_author_works)
console.log('doesn\'t work: ', data_author_doesnt_work)
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what that means. Where is it being evaluated before the tryCatch function? I think that the first line passes the 'jsonObj['data'][0]['creators'][0]['description']' to the function in the third line, which then evaluates it in the try statement. That's obviously incorrect, but I don't understand where it goes wrong. Thanks!

Comment: `jsonObj['data'][0]['creators'][0]['description']` is an expression. The JS engine will attempt to evaluate that expression and call `tryCatch` with whatever the expression evaluates to. When there is no artist information, you'll get an error before `tryCatch` is ever called. To confirm this, you can add a `console.log` statement on the line before the `try` inside your function. You'll see that nothing is logged if artist information is missing.

Comment: Awesome, thank you! I ended up just pulling that section out of a function and running it directly in-line. Thank you for helping me figure things out!